# Reduced computer performance when AC power is plugged in on a Dell Latitude 5420

Tags: 11.10, battery

i have Dell Latitude 5420 laptop and yesterday i have istalled 11.10 Ubuntu. All instalation process was done on battery power, so there was no problem on performance. Today i have plugged in my computer and tried to turn on Ubuntu and there is a problem.

When computer runs on battery power performace is perfect, but when i plug to charge battery all system slows down and mouse moves very slovly.

Answer (score 2):

Please try to customize the parameters for both modes (baterry/charger) with this tool:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/jupiter
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install jupiter
```

This tool also resolve the problem with the excesive baterry consumption present en kernels 2.6.38-3.1.x-3.2.x.